# Globally overriding styles from Appcompat 21

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm currently porting an app to the r21 appcompat-v7 lib (and Android Studio/Gradle). In this app, pretty much every widget is styled somehow, which works fine with the previoulsy used r19 version of the lib.

Since r21 many styles get just ignored by the system/lib and Material ones are used. This seems to be especially true for `Spinner`, `ActionBar` and `EditText` (at least on these I found it). My `RadioButton`s, `CheckBox`es for example are themed just like before.

Here is the relevant XML (v14) for the `Spinner` (Names changed for post):

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
...  
    <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/MySpinner</item>  
...   
</style>  

<style name="MySpinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/list_selector_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

Of course the Theme.MyTheme is set in the manifest application wide.
Now the fun thing is, when I set this style for each `Spinner` in the layouts seperately it works just fine.

So, does anyone know if this is casued by the support library and how I may be able to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppCompat overrides `android:spinnerStyle` property for its Platform theme. Have you already tried to override it instead of `android:dropDownSpinnerStyle`?

Comment: Really sorry that I left this question un-marked. And yes, turns out I forgot to override some properties in the theme hierarchy. It needs a lot of rework anyway. Thanks for the hint!